# How do I fix bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect?

Tags: python, add-on, operator, conversion

I am trying to convert a metaball object to a mesh, but I cant pass this stage. I am basically stuck. I checked out all the bpy.context and context override and bpy.ops  posts and documents and i still can't make these 2 ops work :( I do not understand why they need special context.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\addons\Dupper\__init__.py", line 95, in dupper
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
  File "C:\BLENDER_28\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 200, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect

location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1



def makedup(obj):

    object=obj

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object
    object.select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')



class Dupper(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.dupper"
    bl_label = "dupper"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):

        bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=str(FILE))

        object=bpy.data.objects["mball"]

        makedup(object)

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Recommend you remove `bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=str(FILE))`  Ask yourself do you really want to trash the file you are in by opening another with this operator.?  Add a `print(context.copy())` before and after the operator to examine if  the context is  "refreshed" to be that of the newly opened file. Eg `context.scene` of file A from within  the script is run does not automatically become the  `context.scene` of newly loaded file B...

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. You recommend to remove open_mailfile, but how do I open a .blend file in a script that? Is it impossible to do?

Comment: You can open a blend file with `bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(...)` The issue is the context  directly after opening  the file with the operator (like above).  Did you examine the difference in context, pre and aft?  Why not convert the objects in the blend you are in? (which your code will do if you remove the open mainfile operator)  . Why the need to open another file to convert?  Look into running in background mode where you can pass the file and the script via command line (or call in python  with for example `subprocess.Popen("blender -b foo.py -P convert_meta.py".split(" "))`.

Comment: I am not around my desktop yet, I will try your options and write back here. Basically I am opening the file because I am modifying some options in that file and then I need to save it back as a different file. I do not understand your comment about converting? Do you mean saving objects as a .obj type thing? I will investigate the mode, I assume I can get the blender.exe path properly so I can pass it? In any case thanks for the recommendations

Comment: Ok I tried running the subprocess method, it might work except that I cant make Blender to to load my local module (local to the script) :(

Comment: @batFINGER so I tried spawning a new Blender, it works. Almost, I hit another block with context error when I am trying to run "bpy.ops.sculpt.dynamic_topology_toggle()" in the script :( Any recommendation? I tried running it in the calling script and the running script without much luck :( I am saving the scene in the script runs in the subproces, then I open the scene in main Blender process.